# How to scan files/images for antivirus in c# before uploading the images in azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, c#-3.0, antivirus

I am using .net framework 4.5.1, I want to scan files for virus with in app service only. It is web app project, I want to do it without web/worker role

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please show any attempts made so far?

Comment: I have tried to use clam AV, but it require worker role in azure cloud service, so I want to do it in web api/c# only with some dll installed or running command line prompt for virus scanning ? so that it will work when i publish web app in azure

Answer (score 0):

When using Azure App Service, the underlying service that hosts the web app has Microsoft Antimalware enabled on it. This is used to protect Azure App Service infrastructure and does not run on customer content. [[doc]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-antimalware)

There are ideas on how to achieve this already on S/O.
[Virus Scanning Uploaded files from Azure Web/Worker Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567922/virus-scanning-uploaded-files-from-azure-web-worker-role)

Comment: Is there any way to scan files without using web/worker role and do it in web api/c# only with some dll installed or running command line prompt for virus scanning ? so that it will work when i publish web app in azure

Comment: Windows Defender is available in the D:\Program Files\Windows Defender\ folder of your web app.  You could try to call it from your web app but I have not tested this and have no idea if it's supported.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/gg131918(v=msdn.10)