# Virus Scanning on uploaded file to Azure Block Storage via Azure Web App as of 2020

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My project needs to perform virus scan on uploaded files via Azure AppService web app. Files will be stored in Azure Block Storage if they are cleaned. Otherwise, they are rejected to users.

My question: How should I implement this, does Azure provide built-in anti-virus scan?

[Virus Scanning Uploaded files from Azure Web/Worker Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567922/virus-scanning-uploaded-files-from-azure-web-worker-role)

Comment: As the answer says there’s currently no real solution to this apart from the Symantec extension, we’re integrating Scanii’s API currently.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, there's Thread protection in Azure Security Center, but it's not real time and does not offer an API which you can use to trigger the scan:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/threat-protection#threat-protection-for-azure-storage-

The alternative is to use 3rd party solutions such as Symantec Cloud Workload Protection:

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/symanteccorporation.symccwps-app?tab=Overview

You can also use open source tools and build your own solution